# How to execute a specific code in a defined period -Django-

Tags: python, django, timer

I would like to know how to automatically execute a code in Django within a defined period of time.
I'm building a web crawler that collects information and stores it in a JSON file and a function that reads the file and stores the file information in a SQLite database. This information is rendered and visible on my website. At the moment I have to run the crawler and the function that saves the data in a database with a click on a button, but that is very ineffective. It would be better if the database information were updated automatically, about every 6 hours (of course, only if the server is running).

Comment: `.update()` inside a `for` loop should work.

Comment: you can use the celry library which provides the async and schedule job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the code on your webserver and you have the permissions then a `CRON` job (Linux) or `Scheduled Task` (Windows) will do what you want.  Set your cron job to run every six hours and to call your Django script.

You can run the script as a Django command line, eg `manage.py mycommand` or run as a stand-alone PY file where you include the libs and run `django.setup()`

Or if you want the crawler to be run from within the context of your webserver then your cron job can initiate a GET request using `HTTPIE`. That gives you a nice API approach.

When I run this I have a flag in a database (a model called Job) that records what is running just in case my scheduled task is already running when the cron gets called, I have some very long-running asynchronous tasks and I tend to use `cron` rather than `Celery`.

If you are running your site on `AWS` or `GCP` then both have a cron equivalent. Eg you could create a `GCP cloud scheduler` [link](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) that fires off a GET to your webserver that triggers the code to run the crawler.